# Find and Grep Statement

Tags: grep

I am trying to find the location and frequency of the following patterns

> x37 x41
>   x42 x43
>   x44 x45
>   x46 x63
>   x75 x76
>   x81 x82
>   x83 x95
>   x96 Bottom1
>   Bottom2 Bottom3
>   Middle Middle1
>   Right1 Top3

in a htdocs directory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want instructions on using `find` and `grep`, you should go to Super User or possibly unix.stackexchange.com.  If this is instead a programming question, please explain further.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the locations:

```
grep -rE '(x(37|4[1-6]|63|7[56]|8[123]|9[56]))|Bottom[123]|Middle1?|Right1|Top3' /directory/to/search
```

This will give you the frequencies:

```
grep -orE '(x(37|4[1-6]|63|7[56]|8[123]|9[56]))|Bottom[123]|Middle1?|Right1|Top3' /directory/to/search | sort | uniq -c
```